# The second resonance of string?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, resonance, string

What is the relationship between "the second resonance " and string and the wavelength. Like in this question: if the length of the string is 2cm with second resonance, then what is wavelength?

Comment: You know about `(speed)=(wavelength)*(frequency)` and that the wave speed is constant if the tension is constant.

Answer (score 3):

The first resonant vibrational mode for a string clamped at both ends looks like:

[image: fundamental harmonic]

You should be able to deduce the wavelength from that diagram.  The second mode looks like:

[image: second harmonic]

Both of the images above are from http://www.clickandlearn.org/Physics/sph3u/Music/Music.htm and that site will spell it out in more detail for you.

If your string length is $2\:\mathrm{cm}$ then the wavelength of the first vibrational harmonic is $4\:\mathrm{cm}$.  The second vibrational mode has a wavelength of $2\:\mathrm{cm}$.

If the string is open at one or both ends the modes are different however using the link above you should be able to figure it out without issue.